# is it becoming more popular to return strings instead of objects from service methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I seem to remember reading that deserialization was somewhat expensive in C#.  I have a C# service that was returning an object.  The object will be used as JSON by downstream clients.

Now that JSON has become the most popular service response format and now that javascript frameworks have become the preferred front-end implementation, is it becoming more common for services to simply return JSON strings instead of objects?

If a C# service method returns an object this means that the object had to be mapped from the repo layer which is a cost. And the object will be serialized again as it's passed over the wire to the client.  So are more services simply returning strings instead of objects?

Also, Web API has the concept of returning a JSONResult. What's the difference in returning a string from a service method as opposed to returning a JSONResult from a service method?

Comment: I think you  are confused. A JSON object is a JSON string.

Comment: A JsonResult will automatically be serialized into a JSON string when responding to an HTTP request. The benefit is that you can use the object in code to access the underlying data without deserializing the response again. For example, when testing a controller method.

Comment: You can use Mark Gravell's [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for [much better serialization](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/06/05/choose-protocol-buffers/), not nearly as expensive as others.. and there are a few to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, have to nitpick on your language.

Services have NEVER returned objects.  They return bit streams, which are a serialized representation of objects.  Sometimes those bit streams use UTF encoding, and in fact are strings, which contain XML, which often (e.g. with S**O**AP) represent objects.  But they are still strings.

JS**O**N, too, is a string, which is a serialized representation of an object or objects (that is what the O stands for).

So your question is somewhat meaningless.  Services continue to return objects, it's just that their serialized representation has changed a bit.  Instead of using a SOAP representation, developers are turning to simpler and less chatty representations like JSON.

Answer (score 2):

*Done well*, string serialization can still be efficient; maybe not quite as brutal on the bytes as raw binary, but it doesn't need to be horrible. If the data you are sending is going to fit in the same number of packets between string and binary serialization, then the network time isn't going to be that much different. So *in those cases*, json can be attractive in terms of convenience and simplicity. If you need the absolute best performance above all other considerations, raw binary (bespoke, or something like protobuf) is probably your go-to. In many cases, json is certainly a *lot* more attractive than XML, which was the default in the history of web-services.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to work with strings throughout your service (which would be highly unproductive, problematic and defeat the whole point of using .NET), at some point in your service it is going to need to serialize objects to a string which could be json, xml or some other formatted string to be included in the HTTP response from your service.

Web API frameworks and many before it allow you to create a representation of your service using .NET objects which the framework automatically serializes for you.  There'd be no benefit manually serializing your objects and returning strings, all you would be doing is changing the point at which your objects are serialized and introducing redundant code.